# Different sign up form for firefox and chrome on twitter

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, user-agent

I noticed that Twitter uses a different sign up form for firefox and for chrome in their mobile site. It seems they use the user agent string to send either form. Why would this be? The difference is not just aesthetic. On firefox, they ask for more information, and they show a captcha, but not on chrome. Why protect one, but not the other?